# Python Google Search: Too Many Requests

Tags: python, google-search

I'm using a Python code which uses the googlesearch module to fetch the position of a site from a Google search.

```
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

item = "windows xp download"

for j in search(item, tld="co.in", num=20, stop=20, pause=2):
    print(j)
```

That works for some runs, then I get a:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

I see there are some hints to set the header object with a User-agent:

```
requests.get(link, headers={'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
```

However I don't have direct access to the request object in that piece of code. Can you recommend a way to do that?

Comment: I think you missed the point of the ImortError. It basically gives you the same message you are printing, but more importantly, it stops your program from running if the module is missing. Catching the error defeats that purpose. At least add `raise` at the end of the `except` block.

Comment: Short answer: stop spamming the site. Add a timer between requests or something.

Comment: See: [https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/issues/18](https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/issues/18)

Comment: I don't know the exact limits for N & P but in principle Google will only permit N requests within period P before it emits HTTP 429. You either need to make fewer requests or add some artificial delay