# googlesearch-python doesnt scrape the internet

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of companies and I need to find their URL. I have tried the following but I keep getting the error

> Error searching for System73 URL: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

and it is like that for all companies.

What should I change in the code to make it work? Tried to google it but did not succed.

Here is my code:

```
from googlesearch import search

companies = [
    "System73", "Bo Growth", "SDG Group", "Plexus", "Amadeus", 
    "Novatec Software Engineering España SL", "Ibermática", "Swiss RE", 
    "EY", "Oxigent", "OpenNebula Systems", "Bunge", "Deloitte", "e-Frontiers", 
    "N26", "INTEL", "ToBeIT", "Globant", "Nutanix", "Ubisoft", "We Bring", 
    "ELCA Security", etc.
]

company_urls = {}

for company in companies:
    try:
        # Searching for the official website using Bing (you can adjust the search engine if needed)
        search_query = f"{company} official website"
        search_results = search(search_query, num=1, stop=1)
        
        # Extracting the first result URL
        company_url = next(search_results, None)
        company_urls[company] = company_url
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error searching for {company} URL: {e}")

# Print the results
for company, url in company_urls.items():
    print(f"{company}: {url}")
```

Comment: That would only happen if you don't really have the `f` at the beginning of your f-string in the `except` block. The f-string should replace `{variable}` with the value.

Comment: I have the f it print the company name and the error.

Comment: Get rid of `try/except` while debugging, so you see the full error and traceback.

Comment: If it's printing the company name and error, what is the actual error?

Comment: It does not print the urls for the company which is what I want.

Comment: I mean what is the error message that replaces `{e}`?

Comment: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563833/python-google-search-too-many-requests and particularly the link to https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/issues/18